# Can i replace snakeyaml library in Spring boot starter with jackson dataformat yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, snakeyaml

Snakeyaml is blocked due to vulnerability. And my build fails due to this.

Also, looks like spring framework cannot run without it..

Is it possible to replace it with jackson dataformat ?

In general, can i replace jars from the dependency tree of an artifact ?

EDIT 1:

Error message:

```
18:52:47.125 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to load Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' but snakeyaml was not found on the classpath
        at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:36)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
```

Comment: There's nothing in Spring Framework or Spring Boot that requires SnakeYAML. Spring Boot needs it if you want to use `application.yaml` to configure your application. If you use `application.properties` it should not be required. What failure do you see when you try to run without it?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson spring-boot-starter pulls in snakeyaml. see - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.7.3/spring-boot-starter-2.7.3.pom

Comment: @Andy added error message in the edit. Also, i am importing a library that uses yaml..

Comment: @JohnWilliams It's included in the starter purely for convenience. As you've noted in your answer, it can be excluded if you're happy to use `.properties` files to configure your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without application.yml, ie use application.properties then you can remove the vulnerable snakeyaml jar as follows, ie with an `exclusion` tag.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks John.. but i am still looking for a way to replace snakeyaml with jackson.. is it possible? or is snakeyaml tightly coupled with the spring libraries?

Comment: Moving to jackson-dataformat-yaml is not going to help because it uses snakeyaml - see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.14.2. Deserialising yaml in Java is pretty much synonymous with snakeyaml.